I'm looking to modify an electronic toy to function whenever it's switched on instead of at the push of a button, would anyone be able to help?
I've been modifying a simple electronic toy that consists of an on/ off switch to control the power, a button to push to perform ten seconds of movement, and wires connecting to the limbs of the toy. The modification I'm stuck on is how to convert the toy to no longer rely on the button and instead automatically function when it's switched on so I can leave it on permanently as if someone were pushing the button repeatedly. What would you recommend, and should I remove the button altogether or be wiring something else in to work alongside it? I've heard a 555 could be good but I don't quite understand how they work.

There are many tutorials on 555 timer IC so that's not a problem you can't solve. A bigger problem is, we don't know how your toy reads the button so we don't know what you need between 555 and the button to simulate repeated pushes.

use relay contact in parallel with the button

is that all ? 1 button on off every x seconds. or is it more than 1 alternating ? or more

it might make more sense to use a microcontroller ... https://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/ATtiny85-pushbutton-circuit.php

Does this toy run from a 9 V block battery?

What happens if you hold the button down ermanently (eg use a clip) and then turn the toy on?  what is the power source for the toy?

We need more information, such as:
a) What is the toy’s supply voltage?
b) How does the push button acts (does it connects positive or negative voltage to the control board or does it closes two contacts on the control board)?
c) If you keep the push button pressed, what happens (is the action repeated once, or repeated indefinitely)?
If it is necessary to press the push button every time for the action be performed, the solution with a 555 may be interesting. In this case, you can build a circuit like this:

Note that:

LM555 needs at least 4.5V to work. You can use the CMOS version (LMC555) which can be powered with a lower voltage (see device datasheet);

This circuit assumes that we know nothing about the IC on the PCB. Using a relay is a possible solution, but it is not optimized;

The waveform created by this circuit is approximately as follows:



Depending on how the push button works, the 555 output can be used directly to activate the control board and generate desired action(s).

A) Looks to have a couple of 16V capacitors, and takes 3 1.5V AAA batteries
B) I'm not entirely sure, though if it helps it's soldered directly onto the motherboard rather than being connected by a cable or anything like that.
C) The button does nothing when held unfortunately, it seems it's the act of the button being pushed that activates the movement. Pushing twice quickly doesn't restart the movement, but pushing it a second time is required for a second bout of movement once the first has finished

a) With a voltage of 4.5V it will be possible to use the TTL version of the 555. However, the CMOs version is more recommended due to its lower consumption; b) Unfortunately, it is necessary to know more about this button to define which driver to use for the 555 output and c) Ok, the 555 solution (except for item b) should work. Can you take photos of the circuit board and button?

https://imgur.com/a/s0TyPN5
Pictures there, hopefully that helps. The wires all connect to the different moving parts/ battery compartment and the button under where it says S1 is the one that requires pushing to start movement

I can't (obviously) visualize tracks below the IC. It seems to me that S1 connects IC's pin 1 to another pin that I cannot identify. Clearly this IC sends signals to transistor Q1 which I assume drives a motor (M+ and M-). If you can identify the IC and also measure voltages at the S1 button terminals, it would be helpful.

That'll be beyond my ability so I might just have to trial and error a bit with it.
Hypothetically, if I go with the CMOS 555 would that replace the button or be integrated alongside it?

In this case, you can try using a relay. This solution is not optimized since it consumes more energy. Relay must be connected in parallel with S1 terminals. I updated my answer to consider this solution.
It seems that PCB is prepared to receive a speaker (SP+; SP-) and a buzzer (BZ). The IC seems to be a multiple PWM generator (WTN4 series, maybe).
Without measurements, I cannot propose another solution. If you could confirm that IC's pin 1 is connected to 4.5V, we can eliminate U2, D3, Q1 and R2.

Another solution would be to determine motor on/off times and use 555 + relay/transistor to directly activate the motor, bypassing the entire circuit on current PCB. To do this, you need to change  C1, R3 and R4 in my diagram to achieve the desired times.
